# SQL: How to add GROUP BY/ORDER BY clauses in a query with an enclosed case statement

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by, case

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 
    (SELECT dbtables.[name] as 'back_end_name', 
            CASE
                WHEN dbtables.[name] LIKE '_Result%' AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], LEN(dbtables.[name]) - 7) AS int) = CalculationID
                THEN Calculation.Name
                WHEN dbtables.[name] LIKE '_History%' 
                THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 9 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 1) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 10 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 2) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 11 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 3) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        ELSE 'N/A'
                    END 
                ELSE 'N/A'
            END AS front_end_name,
            indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
            indexstats.page_count,
            indexstats.record_count
        FROM Calculation, HistoryMap, sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Sampled') AS indexstats
        INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
        WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID() AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 30) tmp
WHERE front_end_name NOT LIKE '%N/A%'
```

I have the following query which works, however some data in 'front_end_name' duplicates when I only want 1 instance, so I add 'GROUP BY front_end_name' at the very end, but it returns the error "Column 'tmp.back_end_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause". Why is it talking about back_end_name now?

When I add the GROUP BY after the first WHERE clause, at the end of the enclosed query, it says front_end_name is an invalid column name.

Also, I want to ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent. Obviously I can't do this at the very end of the query, because indexstats is local to inside the enclosed query. When I try to do it at the end of the enclosed query, it tells me "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Any tips as to how I can add GROUP BY front_end_name and ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent to my existing query? Still pretty new to SQL so I'm learning. I am trying to avoid writing the case statement more than once.

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] the question and show us the schema by posting the relevant `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data for that tables as `INSERT INTO` statements, the expected result as tabular text and don't forget to tag the DBMS you are using and its version.

Answer (score 0):

Do not simply add `GROUP BY` anywhere to remove duplicates. This is used mostly for aggregation purposes. Step back and think about your needs.

- First, ask yourself: when ***front_end_name*** repeats, does the other columns (`back_end_name`, `avg_fragmentation_in_percent`, `page_count`, `record_count`) repeat as well? Likely they do not repeat since your outer query uses `DISTINCT`.
- Now, think about your data. How to handle the non-repeating columns for every repeating `front_end_name`? Likely this is due to the granularity of joined tables, `Calculation`, `HistoryMap`, `sys.tables`, etc. which can have one-to-many or many-to-many relationship per your calculated ***front_end_name***.

Using CTE to hold your raw, ***base*** results, consider aggregating the other columns to avoid repeated names

```
WITH base AS (
     SELECT dbtables.[name] AS back_end_name, 
            CASE
                WHEN dbtables.[name] LIKE '_Result%' AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], LEN(dbtables.[name]) - 7) AS int) = CalculationID
                THEN Calculation.Name
                WHEN dbtables.[name] LIKE '_History%' 
                THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 9 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 1) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 10 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 2) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        WHEN LEN(dbtables.[name]) = 11 AND CAST(RIGHT(dbtables.[name], 3) AS int) = HistoryID
                        THEN HistoryMap.TableName
                        ELSE 'N/A'
                    END 
                ELSE 'N/A'
            END AS front_end_name,
            indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
            indexstats.page_count,
            indexstats.record_count
        FROM Calculation, HistoryMap, sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Sampled') AS indexstats
        INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
        WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID() AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 30
)

SELECT back_end_name,
       front_end_name,
       AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS avg_page_count,   -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
       SUM(page_count) AS sum_page_count,                     -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
       SUM(record_count) AS sum_record_count                  -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
FROM base
GROUP BY back_end_name,               -- GROUP BY REQUIRES ALL NON-AGG COLUMNS PRESENT IN CLAUSE
         front_end_name
ORDER BY AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent)
```

Alternatively, aggregate `front_end_name` if you know the reason for repetition:

```
WITH base AS (
    ...
)

SELECT back_end_name,
       MAX(front_end_name) AS front_end_name,
       AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS sum_page_count,   -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
       SUM(page_count) AS sum_page_count,                     -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
       SUM(record_count) AS sum_record_count                  -- ADJUST AGG FUNCTION TO NEEDS
FROM base
GROUP BY back_end_name
ORDER BY AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent)
```